# Is cycling an aerobic or anaerobic exercise? What is the effect of cycling on weight loss?

Tags: safety, health

I like to do cycling and I want to lose weight through cycling. But my friend told me about cardio instead of cycling, since cycling burns calories at a much slower rate. Is it true? So what's better to lose calories faster, cycling or other exercises?

Comment: Tell your friend he needs to do his "cardio" for three or four **HOURS**.  Or tell him to keep his speed at 40 kph or higher.  Then ask him if "cycling burns calories at a much slower rate".  Your friend is, umm, misinformed.

Comment: Any exercise programme will have different things mixed together, to minimise boredom and work different muscles.   You could do mix it up with cardio one day, ride your bike the next day, and so on .   Yoga, wood-chopping, and running on other days, then have a light day where you go for a walk.  You do you.

Comment: What safety concerns do you have? (I ask because you tagged this question with "safety")

Comment: @PaulH Umm... safety from the side effects of gaining weight (heart disease, ...)?

Comment: Ignore all advise from someone who says you should do cardio instead of cycling.  Best advice would be to do something you love, not too much, not too little, above all, don't get injured.  If you love cycling more than any other exercise, there is no better activity, its low risk of injury, and you can do as little or much as you want as often as you want.

Comment: @Paul Safety is a big concern for many people getting into exercise. For people who are out of shape or unused to exercise, (or both), injury prevention while getting back into shape should be their #1 priority, and any advice given should be focused on injury prevention over results.  It is hard to get results if you are nursing injuries and cannot exercise.  (Which is why I would caution against gym based 'cardio' training, where one hour of 'one hour max' effort is considered 'Cardio')

Comment: Was this ever a real question ?

Comment: Depending on how much power you put in, cycling is aerobic, or anaerobic, or it makes you lose weight. It's your choice.

Comment: I've read that cycling is one of the most efficient modes of transport known to man, in terms of calories per person per mile.

Comment: @stannius That stat raises a lot of questions. For starters: "Efficient" in what sense? (Max consumption or max conservation?) Citing cycling as an efficient "mode of transport" (rather than "form of exercise") makes me think the comparison is total energy required, regardless of source: e.g., riding a bus means **the bus** consumes X amount of energy per rider per mile, which may or may not be more than what passengers would expend by cycling. But that isn't really relevant to exercise, since **none** of the energy consumed by a bus is supplied _by the passengers themselves_.

Answer (score 24):

The answer to the Title question, "*Is cycling an aerobic or anaerobic exercise?*", is yes.

> Aerobic exercises are endurance-type exercises that increase a person’s heart rate and breathing rate over relatively long durations.
> Anaerobic exercises are exercises that involve short bursts of intense activity.
> — [Aerobic vs. anaerobic exercises: What to know](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-exercises)

Taking a long ride will provide aerobic exercise.
You'll be burning more energy than usual, and will be continually breathing faster than usual in order to maintain a consistent level of oxygen in the blood.

If during that ride you occasionally have a quick sprint or a short steep climb, so that when it's over you find yourself needing to stop and breathe very heavily, it's anaerobic.
The oxygen in your blood will be briefly and temporarily depleted.

---

As for your purpose, in general, exercise by itself is not a good way to lose weight.
Exercise *does* burn calories (about 10 per minute for moderate cycling), but for most people the major effect of this is that they end up feeling hungrier afterward, and often end up eating more calories than what they just burned.

Exercise *is* a good thing, and given what site this is, obviously *cycling* is the best form of exercise, but it should be used in conjunction with other methods of weight loss.

The exercise that really loses weight is the exercise of restraint.

Eating because one feels hungry is a great way to gain weight, not lose it.

Following exercising, one will feel hungry, and that is good.
It is proof that some fat has been burned, and the body is simply saying that it needs to be fed so it can refill the fat cells.
To act on that request will simply restore any weight that was lost due to the exercise, and perhaps some more.

Most people, especially those that are overweight, will be exhausted after 45 minutes of moderate cycling.
But in terms of weight, they could have lost *twice as much* simply by not eating a Big Mac Meal and feeling hungry for a few hours.

In fact, the general rule is that the most effective way to lose weight is to feel hungry.

Exercise is great for strong bones, better endurance, and more effective respiratory and circulatory systems.
But it should not be seen as a quick and easy method of weight loss.

---

And always avoid fructose. It is the one carbohydrate that doesn't "spoil your dinner".
It has an extremely low [glycemic index](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diseases-and-conditions/glycemic-index-and-glycemic-load-for-100-foods) and can take hours before it might be converted to blood sugar (dextrose), though by then it is more likely to have been stored as fat.

(Long distance cyclists might want to take the opposite advice.)

Comment: OTOH eating during exercise takes more thought than eating when it's just a stroll to the kitchen to get food, even if you have food to hand on the bike.  I actually tend to eat *less* on days when I spend many hours riding than on sedentary days. I'm also not alone in finding that on fasted (before breakfast) or unfed (after a meal but with no calories during a ride of several hours) rides, it's only when I stop that I get hungry.

Comment: Also, building cycling muscles and getting fitter will increase your basal metabolic rate; if the goal is weight loss this will make a disciplined approach to eating go further

Comment: Exercise can totally help with weight loss. My commute is 6km in each direction and takes 20 minutes. According to my power meter I burn more than 100kcal in each direction. That’s 200kcal more per day I can eat just by commuting. A two hour bike ride can easily burn more than 1000kcal which is a whole pizza. I’m not that fit and relatively light at 66kg. A fitter, heavier person would burn even more. I’ve counted calories, I eat more than 2500kcal every day and I’m not gaining weight because of the exercise.

Comment: @Michael, I didn't say that exercise doesn't help with weight loss. My point was that unless one also takes calorie intake into consideration, it's very easy to unwittingly eat extra to make up for the burned calories. Exercise is a good idea even if one isn't trying to lose weight, but for weight loss it is only part of the answer, not *the* answer.

Comment: @ChrisH says "*I'm also not alone in finding that on fasted … rides, it's only when I stop that I get hungry.*".  Definitely. Once your body switches into burning fat mode your blood sugar remains relatively high and you don't feel hungry. Later when you eat something, the blood sugar goes higher, your body switches out of fat burning mode, your blood sugar goes down again, and you experience hunger. This is the point where you choose whether to regain the fat you just burned (if you have stable weight) or to feel hungry for a while (if you want to lose weight).

Comment: Regarding fructose: it's the main carb in fruits. Fruits can help with satiety as they have fiber and water, and they have vitamins. By avoid fructose, I assume you mean avoid stuff sweetened with fructose syrup - but isn't that not terribly different from just reducing your dessert intake?

Comment: @WeiwenNg, in nature fructose tends to appear with dextrose (glucose) in approximately equal proportion, either separately (e.g. honey) or combined (e.g. sucrose).  When you eat the fruit, you get the glucose immediately, giving you energy now, and by the time you've used that up, the fructose has been converted to glucose to give another boost. It's like when one's mother sends a child out to play and gives them a snack for now and a snack for later.

Comment: @WeiwenNg  "*By avoid fructose, I assume you mean avoid stuff sweetened with fructose syrup*" — When there is unnaturally far more fructose than dextrose in a snack, there is no immediate increase in blood sugar and so one still feels hungry and often ends up eating something else too. Meanwhile that fructose gets converted to lipids in the blood. Normally the lipids would be converted to dextrose when the blood sugar drops again, but if one has eaten more food the levels don't drop and the unneeded lipids are stored in the fat cells. So eating what one's body suggests, ends up as weight gain.

Comment: These Comments will end up forming a thesis for human physiology and weight loss if they do not stop. The answer adequately responds to the simplistic nature of the question, behind the question is one of the most complex physiological and psychological problems modern humans face.   Oversimplification is the greatest evil in this subject, along with far too much dogma and not enough common sense.

Comment: Additionally to the point about heavy breathing indicating anaerobic exercise, if your muscles start to ‘burn’, that’s also anaerobic (though possibly only slightly so). The burn is from the buildup of lactic acid, which is the main byproduct of the primary anaerobic metabolic cycle.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn said "*The burn is from the buildup of lactic acid*". See [3 Myths About Lactic Acid Debunked](https://recoupfitness.com/blogs/news/3-myths-about-lactic-acid-debunked#:~:text=MYTH,LACTIC%20ACID).

Comment: One thing I'd like to add is that it is important to avoid Bonking. Especially on very long rides you can do real damage to your whole body by not eating enough, and it just makes the experience terrible. It's better to get in the habit of small gains often rather than huriting yourself once a year.

Comment: @Borgh is bonking dangerous? I always assumed that once you ate a snack the incident is over.

Comment: *about 10 per minute for moderate cycling* That's a bit optimistic.  10 cal/min is 167 watts.  For an average cyclist, that's enough power to average close to 20 mph/30 kph on level ground.  15 mph is more like 100W, or 6 cal/min.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I got the number from
[How Many Calories Do You Burn Biking?](https://www.healthline.com/health/how-many-calories-do-you-burn-biking#slow-vs-fast),
which got it from
[Calories burned in 30 minutes of leisure and routine activities - Harvard Health](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diet-and-weight-loss/calories-burned-in-30-minutes-for-people-of-three-different-weights).

Comment: Upright and breathing burns about 50-100 Calories/hour- many of those "How many calories do you burn doing X" use a base rate of a dead person.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Since you're nitpicking about 1 vs 1.67, I'll happily nitpick about 1 vs 1000 : 10 cal / min is 167 **milli**watts according to your formula. 10 **kcal** / min would be ~167 W.

Comment: @mattnz: Indeed. It's a bit depressing how many kilocalories we already burn by simply sitting on a couch. I really enjoyed reading this [article](https://mb-soft.com/public2/humaneff.html), which suggests that an efficient way to lose bodyfat is to sleep with thin sheets, simply because we spend ~1/3 of our lifetime in a bed, and radiate ~100W even when we're not doing anything.

Comment: @stannius there are worse things you can do, and none of the things I know of are permanent. But a bonk happens when a few different storages are empty, and those take some time to refill. A snack will solve the immediate problem, some rest (and dinner) will take care of the rest.

Comment: @Borgh I can think of a few ways it can be secondarily dangerous: 1) If you get light headed enough to accidentally fall. 2) if you are far out and get yourself stranded without the energy to get back to civilization (I'd say, follow hikers' "10 essentials" approach and always bring more food, water, and clothing than you expect to need). 3)  I found an entire article about bicyclists who thought they were bonking, but were actually experiencing serious heart trouble.

Answer (score 13):

Cycling at moderate intensity is mostly an aerobic cardio exercise.

How many calories you burn in an hour depends on your power output. A heavy professional cyclist (90kg, <strike>6W/kg</strike> 5W/kg) can probably burn around 2000kcal in a single hour when cycling all-out. For an amateur at a less-than-all-out intensity it’s more like 500–1000kcal in an hour.

Other cardio exercises like running or rowing have similar rates.

In my opinion cycling has several advantages for burning calories:

- Even complete beginners can do it for >30 minutes. With a bit of training two hours are very achievable.
- Risk of overuse injuries is low and time for recovery is short. If you don’t push too hard even an amateur can go cycling for a meaningful duration every day.
- The above two points are partly possible because intensity can be adjusted in a wide range thanks to gear shifting.
- With a power meter you can measure calories burned pretty accurately.
- You can integrate it into your daily life. Commuting, shopping, visiting friends or family, going to a restaurant … many of those activities require travel in a 5–25km distance which is ideal for cycling, even for a beginner.

That being said, there is no magic recipe for burning calories. If you are consuming 3000kcal every day, are unwilling/unable to reduce intake and still want to lose weight you’ll simply have to exercise for more than an hour every day. And that hour of exercise can be negated in 5 minutes by eating two big chocolate bars.

Comment: Your calorie estimates *may* be a bit high. I’m not 100% certain. I can report that a moderate pace 80 mile solo ride, with me at 135-145 lbs, typically burns a reported 1900-2200 calories over 4-6 hours moving time. (NB: that’s estimated calories expended by body, not measured work done by the power meter; there is an assumption about the body’s gross mechanical efficiency, but that parameter varies by individual). Either way, it’s true that long rides can burn a lot of calories, and they’re low impact.

Comment: @WeiwenNg: I’m currently very out of shape due to two hip surgeries. I’m 66kg, 1.8m. On a 1h ride I can still do 167W average power (not all-out and there are a few kilometers of city traffic) for 635kcal (according to Garmin). Of course a person who’s lighter or less fit (or less motivated) can be much lower.

Comment: *2000kcal in a single hour*  That's 556W.  As @WeiwenNg said, that might be a bit high.  Bradley Wiggins at 6'3" topped out with an FTP around 450W or so IIRC, maybe a bit higher.  Hard to believe someone could add another 20% to Wiggin's lung capacity to sustain a 550W+ FTP no matter how big.

Comment: Andy P also told me in the chat that heavier pro riders seem to have lower FTP. So I guess for a 90kg pro rider around 5W/kg would indeed be a better assumption. Still ends up around 2000kcal in an hour. Not that those numbers are relevant for us mere mortals, but it’s always interesting to see where the human limits are.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Just curious, how do you calculate 556W? This seems to be equal to 2000kJ / h, and not 2000kcal / h. Do you assume that one kcal of nutritional energy is converted to 1 kJ of mechanical energy by the human body while cycling, with an efficiency of ~ 1 / 4.18?

Comment: @EricDuminil A kcal burned by your body is almost exactly 1 kJ of mechanical energy output.  Human bodies are a bit less than 25% efficient, and 1 kJ is .23 kcal - making the conversion just about perfect.  So if you measure the kJ you expend exercising, you pretty much also measure the calories you burned.  And yes, the calories that usually get reported as "burned" by various other methods usually exceed measured kJ, often by quite a bit - they're bogus.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Thanks for the clarification. Since this calculation depends on a varying human efficiency factor, and uses an approximation (2000kcal) as an input, it might be a good idea to leave out some significant figures in the result. 556W seems to be a very precise result for a somewhat inaccurate calculation.

Comment: @EricDuminil Why do you assume 2000 cal/hr should only be considered to have one significant digit?  Zeros **are** significant digits in the real world, and 2,000 means 2,000.  You can't buy a million dollar house and only show up with $900,000 at closing because "they're the same to the only significant digit in the price".

Comment: @AndrewHenle "*around* 2000kcal"

Comment: @EricDuminil *2000kcal in a single hour That's 556W.*  No "around" at all.

Comment: @AndrewHenle. Sigh... There's definitely an "around", in the answer we're commenting about. There are enough people already who have difficulty understanding power and energy units, it's not helping them at all to hide implicit efficiencies and to basically claim that "4.18: That's 1. No around at all". I'm sure you know and understand what you want to communicate, but the shortcuts you take might leave the impression you don't. Just my 8.36 cents.

Comment: @EricDuminil Seriously?  You've come to the internet to argue **significant digits**?!?!?  When ***I*** commented that "*2000kcal in a single hour* That's 556W"  I **meant** 2000kcal.  Now you're arguing the meaning of the digits in ***MY*** comment????

Comment: @AndrewHenle and how many significant digits are known, exactly, in your implicit, hidden conversion factor? 2000kcal/h=556W is wrong any way you look at it, either on physics or bicycle stackexchange. So the significant digits are not the largest problem here. Yelling this formula won't fix it. Goodbye!

Comment: @EricDuminil And good riddance to your useless wackademic fixation and your attempt to tell me what I meant.  Your real-world experience with bicycle racing, measuring power output, and counting calories is what, exactly?

Answer (score 9):

You have several questions mixed into one here. You're asking about "losing calories", and about losing weight. Those are two different things. You also ask if cycling is aerobic or anaerobic, and if cycling is the best option for losing weight. Those are all different questions.

**Burning calories, and aerobic vs anaerobic exercise**

You are constantly burning calories. Even sitting still, you're still burning calories as your heart beats, your lungs inhale, and your body does everything it does to keep you alive. All those things require energy, which your body obtains by burning calories. There are several different ways in which your body burns calories, depending on what you're doing.

During *aerobic* exercise, you are using slow-twitch muscle fibers. Aerobic exercise is less focused on intensity and more on length, such as a long bike ride. Slow-twitch muscle fibers burn calories using your stored fat reserves and the oxygen in your blood, along with small amounts of glucose (sugar).

During *anaerobic* exercise, you are using fast-twitch muscle fibers. Anaerobic exercise is faster-paced and much more intense, such as sprinting. Fast-twitch muscle fibers burn the glucose in your blood stream, and leaves lactic acid in the process, causing that muscle burn that occurs when sprinting.

Both of those methods are burning calories.

**Losing weight**

Anaerobic exercise burns calories faster, since you're burning through all the sugar in your bloodstream. However, you do need to resupply the calories that you're burning. If you use too much of the glucose in your bloodstream, you'll experience exhaustion and fatigue, due to not having any fuel left to burn. Remember, aerobic axercise also needs small amounts of glucose to function. You need to refuel, with carbs and sugar, often when doing anaerobic exercise or risk hypoglycaemia (low blood sugar), a dangerous condition.

Aerobic exercise burns calories more slowly, but does so from your fat reserves as well. Consuming carbs before and during aerobic exercise is recommended, in order to maintain your glucose levels. If you don't eat beforehand, your body automatically goes into preservation mode; you won't burn fat, because your body is making sure to not burn too much because it hasn't had anything, and is trying to make sure you don't starve. If your goal is to burn fat, eat and drink before and during an aerobic session; less so afterwards.

---

Cycling can be both aerobic and anaerobic. Whether your ride is predominantly one or the other depends entirely on how you're riding that day, as well as what discipline you're riding. Road cycling tends to be much more aerobic, with long days in the saddle spending hours on end pedaling. Mountain biking is often much more anaerobic, with lots of short sprints to get up small hills, perform jumps, get over bumps, etc. It all depends on whether your specific training ride is designed more for an aerobic session or anaerobic session.

---

Is cycling the best option for burning calories? It's hard to say. Other sports are more or less demanding on other parts of the body, while cycling is very legs-focused. It's possible that other sports that move more of the body - such as swimming - may be more efficient at burning calories than cycling. Hoever, it is hard to beat cycling when it comes to aerobic sessions; most sports are quite difficult to maintain for six-plus hours, while it's quite doable to maintain that on a bike.

---

Ultimately, any exercise is going to burn more calories and more fat than not doing anything. Pick a sport that your enjoy, and work on it - that's more important than the exact count of calories you're burning doing cycling vs other sports.

<sub>Information in this answer is based on my personal experience as a competitive rider for several years, as well as information I recieved when doing my coaching certification in 2019.</sub>

Comment: "*leaves lactic acid in the process, causing that muscle burn that occurs when sprinting*". Not really. See: [Truth about lactic acid, fatigue, muscle soreness - Sports Illustrated](https://www.si.com/edge/2016/07/21/debunking-myths-lactic-acid-truth-fatigue-recovery-muscle-soreness).

Comment: "*If you don't eat beforehand, your body automatically goes into preservation mode; you won't burn fat, because your body is making sure to not burn too much because it hasn't had anything, and is trying to make sure you don't starve.*". One preservation mode is ketosis, where fat is essentially the only source of energy. ¶ Just this afternoon I did 30 km of up and down hill cycling and always felt like I had plenty of energy, yet I didn't have breakfast until 5:30 pm., having last consumed any calories before 8 pm the night before.

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on the effort you are making. If you produce power, the body must burn some energy storage, quick ATP, blood sugars, then later finally body fats. If your effort on the bike is higher then when doing other cardio activities, you should burn the body fats faster, but you first have to get into the fat-burning regime. That takes some time for all activities.

Normally, cycling is definitely an aerobic activity.For short burst and speeds it can also be anaerobic, but only for short time intervals with very increased effort.

Comment: Doesn't "short time intervals with very increased effort" apply to all anaerobic exercise?

Comment: @ojs Yes, that is the point. My expression is perhaps not the best.

Answer (score 6):

One point that others haven’t covered. Cycling is low impact, and thus it’s comfortable to do it for longer than running. Cycling can be engaging, i.e. it’s very different from an exercise bike, treadmill, or rowing machine in the gym, so it can be pleasant and mentally engaging to do it for longer periods than those activities. Because it is possible and pleasant to do it for prolonged periods, it can be better than other exercises for weight loss.

Naturally, the trade off is that burning more calories takes more time, and you have some barriers to entry in terms of needing to get equipment and relevant skills, e.g. riding, navigating, basic repairs.

Comment: Low impact? is it low impact when I ride my bike and reach my max heart rate in 5 minutes? Is anaerobic training "low impact"?

Comment: @Christine Low impact means there are less stresses on the body - compare riding with running where every footfall hits the ground with some force, generating a shock to the body which affects joints and tissues.

Comment: @Christine other potentially high-impact sports include many ball games. Other low-impact sports include swimming, yoga, rowing. What you describe is basically going for an all-out 5 minute effort. That could be thought of as a semi-anaerobic effort (specifically, you are probably operating near your VO2max, i.e. your aerobic energy system is near max, and you are using a lot of anaerobic power also; think like a mile run). Everyone's lungs are burning at that effort level, no matter how well trained. But that's not 'impact' in the sense I'm using. Also, you could start easier.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite easy to know if an exercise is aerobic or not, but first a bit of physiology.

**First**, your muscles contain various types of fibers: slow fibers for long sustained low intensity effort, and fast fibers for short bursts of high-intensity effort.

These are exercised and developed differently by different types of efforts: basically, your body will become better at doing what you do often. If you only run marathons or only do long bicycle rides at moderate speed, you will train your slow twitch fibers for endurance and you will look like a marathon runner. If you only do sprints, then you will get huge fancy muscles, along with some endurance, but not as much as you'd hope, and the guy with the spindly legs will leave you in the dust on climbs.

**Second**, your muscle cells get their energy from tiny powerplants called mitochondria which burn fat, glucose, and other stuff.

Mitochondria use a range of chemical pathways to burn fuel, they may use several pathways at the same time, but they prioritize the most efficient one depending on what fuel is available, and how much oxygen they get.

The most efficient is aerobic metabolism: burning fuel using oxygen, which exploits all the energy in the fuel and degrades it down to water (which is recycled) and carbon dioxyde (which you breathe out).

The absolute best is burning glucose, it has higher power throughput than burning fat, so glucose has priority over fat. This has an interesting side effect: if you eat a lot of sugary things before exercising, your mitochondria will be very happy to burn it, and they won't use any fat.

The amount of aerobic power you can produce depends on how much oxygen your body can transport to your muscle cells. If you exceed that power, all the oxygen is used up as fast as it comes in, and the excess power is produced by converting glucose into lactic acid without oxygen. This can produce huge power, but the lactic acid accumulates which manifests as a burning sensation in your muscles. When that occurs, it doesn't mean you're over the limit, rather it means you've been over the aerobic limit for a while already. If you keep going, lactate will keep accumulating and you will either stop or throw up.

Just think of a video game: anaerobic is your stamina gauge. It has a certain capacity, it is consumed when you sprint, and when it runs out, your power drops significantly.

Meanwhile, your aerobic capacity is the amount of effort you can sustain at a constant level for a long time, say longer than one hour.

So, to answer your question. Since "effort level" is subjective, let's use an objective measurement instead: time.

A power level you could sustain for many hours: aerobic, burning a mix of glucose and fat. This is pleasant, not really taxing, and if you do it for an hour you arrive feeling good, rested, it doesn't feel like exercising.

A power level you could sustain for 1-2 hours: aerobic, burning mostly glucose.

A power level you could sustain for a few minutes or less (sprinting): aerobic glucose + anaerobic glucose.

When you run out of glucose, power output drops significantly ("hitting the wall") which is not fun, and sprinting is almost impossible.

After sprinting, when you slow down to recover, more oxygen becomes available to recycle all the produced lactates back into pyruvate and glucose. So your thighs stop burning and you feel better without all that lactate. If you don't slow down enough, and stay at the aerobic limit even after a sprint, then all the oxygen is used up to produce power and lactates are not recycled, so your thighs keep burning. If you slow down too much (or stop) then your breathing and heart rate will slow down and lactate recycling will be slower. The optimum seems to be the most pleasant, leisurely pace.

So one important thing is when doing "anaerobic" high intensity interval training (aka sprinting between traffic lights), the cooldown period after the sprint is part of the exercise! During this cooldown your body must either recycle all the lactate that was produced or use it as fuel. Recycling it uses energy and oxygen, so every anaerobic effort is followed by aerobic metabolism to clean up the mess. Anaerobic effort doesn't burn any fat, but the cooldown can burn fat. Later, at home when you rest, you will notice elevated heart rate for several hours because your body is working to replenish glycogen stores, build new muscle, etc.

So, basically, to burn the highest percentage of fat in proportion to the total fuel your body will use, you must ride at a moderate effort level for a very long time. This works but it is not convenient as a weight loss mechanism because you need to spend the whole day on a bike. It is only practical if you do a long bicycle trip. Also the effort is low, so while your body is using more fat than glucose, it is not burning a lot of energy.

The most important thing about exercising is to actually exercise, and in order to do that, it should be fun and pleasant, which means it should be varied and/or practical. If you ride fast, slow, uphill, downhill, with a good mix of cardio, sprints, cooldowns, eat a bit of sugar but not too much, a bit of high glycemic "slow" sugar but not too much. One day a big mountain, the other day lots of small hills, sprints between traffic lights, set yourself challenges, go with friends, etc. The goal should be to get back home well exercised but not entirely exhausted. Then your body will work at elevated metabolism for many hours and burn more fat while you do nothing at all (this requires not eating a huge feast after the ride).

Now about your "knowledgeable" friend:

If you keep your heart rate on the "cardio" range on a bike, you're doing cardio. What makes it cardio is when you keep your heart rate in a specific range for a long enough amount of time, it doesn't matter how you do it, push-ups, cycling, walking uphill, running, whatever. If you want to do it with your arms, you're gonna need pretty big arms though.

For example when the weather doesn't allow cycling, I do cardio by walking up a hill. 300m altitude in 20 minutes is 15m/min, at 100 kilos, about 250 watts, then I walk down.

In fact the only way to do cardio is outside, not in an overheated gym.

If you have any kind of decent leg power output... say, you produce 200 Watts power output on your bike, you will also produce 800 Watts of heat, that's as much as a small electric heater. Outside, you get free air cooling, but to survive this for any length of time indoors, you need a big fan unless the aircon is set to a temperature that would make everyone who isn't doing cardio freeze and leave the gym. In the usual gym which is heated to more than 20°C, forget it. You will overheat, sweat buckets, and exercise at a much lower intensity that you could.